# Compare 2 not identical DTO but have common properties in Fluent Assertion

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

I am writing a unit test for a manual mapper. It maps an object to two different classes but have common properties. how to compare if their properties are equal in fluent assertion?

This is what I tried

```
 var domain = new Domain.ConsentDefinition()
{
     SomeProperty = 1,
     ListOfFirstDTO = new List<FirstDTO>()
     {
          new FirstDTO()
          {
             Name = "Label",
             Age = 18,
          }
     },
     SomeOtherProperty = "one"
}

ef = domain.ToEF();

domain.SomeProperty.Should().Be(ef.SomeProperty);
domain.SomeOtherProperty.Should().Be(ef.SomeOtherProperty);
domain.ListFirstDTO.Should().Equal(ef.ListOfSecondDTO); // This is NOT working
```

classes

```
public class FirstDTO
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int Age {get;set;}
}

public class SecondDTO
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int Age {get;set;}
   public string Email {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override firstDTO's equals so you compare values instead of references:

```
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null || !(obj is FirstDTO) || !(obj is SecondDTO))
            {
                return false;
            }
            
            if(obj is SecondDTO){
              return (this.Name == ((SecondDTO)obj).Name)
                && (this.Age == ((SecondDTO)obj).Age)

            }
            // if obj is instance of FirstDTO check the rest of fields...
        }
```

and run again

```
 domain.ListFirstDTO.Should().Equal(ef.ListOfSecondDTO); // This is NOT working
```

Another more elegant solution with no need of overriding equals would be

```
domain.ListFirstDTO.Select(c => c.Name).Should().Equal(ef.ListOfSecondDTO.Select(c => c.Name);

domain.ListFirstDTO.Select(c => c.Age).Should().Equal(ef.ListOfSecondDTO.Select(c => c.Age);
```

[fluentassertion/collections](https://fluentassertions.com/collections/)

Comment: I just notice it used 'equal' is there a way to use 'be' like others?

Comment: I'm not really sure about it. I think 'Be' is for single properties and won't work for Collections. What you can still do with 'Be' is to iterate through both lists at the same time and compare its values given an index

Comment: Instead of `Equal` use `Should().BeEquivalentTo(ef.ListOfSecondDTO)` - you don't need to override Equals method for it. Look for Dennis's answer

Answer (score 1):

```
domain.Should().BeEquivalentTo(new
{
   SomeProperty = ef.SomeProperty,
   SomeOtherProperty = ef.SomeOtherProperty,
   ListFirstDTO = ef.ListOfSecondDTO
});
```

or

```
domain.Should().BeEquivalentTo(ef, options => options
  .Including(x => x.SomeProperty)
  .Including(x => x.SomeOtherProperty)
  .Including(x => x.ListOfSecondDTO));
```

By default, FA will compare two collections by ignoring the order of the items in the collection. Use `WithStrictOrdering` to control that.

If the second DTO implements `Equals`, then FA will use that. You can override that by using the `ComparingByMembers<T>` option.